# Hibernate 4.2.4 - Returning multiple entities: ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:147 - unknown escape sequence {a.*}

Tags: java, database, hibernate, sqlexception

i´m facing an error while trying to return multiple entities via hibernate. According to the documentation i tried the following select statement:

```
sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT {a.*}, {b.*}  FROM A a LEFT OUTER JOIN B b").addEntity(A.class).addEntity(B.class)
```

Unfortunately it doesn´t work for me, i recieve this error:

```
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:147 - unknown escape sequence {a.*}
```

Just to be sure it´s not only the {table.*}-syntax I tried it with one entity and the same syntax and everything works fine:

```
sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT {a.*} FROM A a ).addEntity(A.class)
```

Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance for your hints and suggestions!

Regards,
Vincent

P.S.: Hibernate Version 4.2.4
Db is MariaDb 10.1.22

@Eugene helped me out of this it works if you do it like this:

```
sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT {a.*}, {b.*}  FROM A a LEFT OUTER JOIN B b on b.ida = a.id").addEntity("a", A.class).addEntity("b", B.class)
```

My false assumptions:

- Hibernate takes care of the join column on it´s own (missing `on b.ida = a.id`)
- Only the order of added entities is decisive ( `addEntity(A.class)` instead of `addEntity("a", A.class)`)

Comment: shouldn't you also add `addJoin`?

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for your hint, never used it before - I´ll check

Comment: Back again - it´s working with and without addJoin for inner joins. To keep it simple I´ve not told yet that I need a left join. For my left join it doesn´t work. I will adapt the example

Comment: Now it´s working - I missed the part "on b.ida = a.id" because i thought hibernate would replace this on its own. Why this results in an unknown escape sequence {a.*} I don´t know. Thanks Eugene for your tip

Comment: `unknown escape sequence` probably because the generation of the query itself is wrong and some validation throws that.

Comment: Just retried this - if you use addClass(A.class) not addClass("a", A.class) you get the unknown escape sequence. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: well this should be obvious I think, since you are creating an `alias` with `addClass...` and without the `a` part who should be aliased?

Comment: I made an answer. may be someone else might find that useful..

Comment: `{a.*}` and `{b.*}` are invalid. It triggers the JDBC escape parsing and neither `a.*` nor `b.*` are valid JDBC escapes. Remove the brackets.

Comment: yes you are right - I thought I only had to take care of the order of the selected entities... :(

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel: thanks for your answer - For Hibernate this syntax is okay, it will be splitted to all fields of the table, before JDBC part is played I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing bits where cause by the lack of `on b.ida = a.id`. Now why the `unknown escape sequence`? Probably because there some validator for the integrity of the query itself that failed.

Comment: Because also the addEntity("a", A.class) was a addEntity(A.class) - i will correct my post, so everybody can comprehend